# Using ALB or ELB as loadbalancer instead of istio-ingressgateway

Tags: istio, zipkin, kiali

We have an EKS cluster in AWS and i am using istio as service mesh in my cluster. We are using istio only for injecting the sidecar into applications and to trace the application traffic through zipkin. To access the application from outside we are not using istio-ingressgateway instead we are using ALB & ELBs

So my problem is I am not getting any traces to zipkin / kiali when i am accessing my application through AWS LBs. Do i have to use istio-ingressgateway to record the traces in zipkin and view in kiali or is there a way to get traces using ALB/ELB as a loadbalancer?

Comment: When installing istio to the cluster, istio-ingressgateway automatically gets created and is exposed via a loadbalancer service meaning there will be a cloud provided loadbalancer associated with it.So ingressgateway is already connected to  a LB provided by AWS.

Comment: Did you change your trace sampling rate to 100%? The default is 1%. More about how to change it [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/configurability/#trace-sampling).

Comment: @sachin thanks for the response. Yeah i know that there will be a LB associated with istio-ingressgateway in aws. We are not using istio-ingressgw as LB for our services , we are using istio as sidecar injector and to trace the API calls between containers using zipkin/kiali. For service we are using ELB/ALB/NLB to access from outside. So when i access my service using ELB/ALB i am not getting traces in zipkin but if i access the same service using istio-ingressgw by creating virtual service and gateway ( istio objects) i am getting traces in zipkin.